# why does docker container automatically logs me out

Tags: docker

I have kylin docker container running....I use the following command to login on an interactive terminal:

```
sudo docker exec -it a5b23ae5deeb /bin/bash
```

it logs me in as admin/root inside the container but after a few seconds I am logged out of the container and back on my ec2 shell (using centos 8)

Please advise what might be the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the main process finishes and the container terminates?

Comment: No...the container is still running

Comment: I restarted the container and now it does not log me out...can anyone explain why this happens?